# Azure Functions Debugging Timer and Http Trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have my timer function run on startup (debugging purposes). As the timer function is running I cannot hit my HTTP trigger functions.

It seems the timer function was blocking thread. So made it async function but same effect.

```
[FunctionName("GetPendingTwilioMsgs")]
    //[TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 30 9 * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {            
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(30000);                
        });
}
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Shouldn't the HTTP trigger functions work regardless of timer function running?

Comment: What is the timer trigger doing exactly?

Comment: Is your code in the function asynchronous? If it isn't and a long-running process, it can block the thread. Just a guess.

Comment: timer trigger is calling dataverse (CRM), calling Twilio api, updating record on CRM.
http trigger are the call backs from Twilio.

I tried to wrap the whole timer trigger in Task.Run, still blocks. I set a break point on entry of timer function thread is 16936, breakpoint in Task.Run thread is 7384. So why is it still blocking. I put a Task.Delay in my update function. I can't hit Http trigger functions. I'm baffled.

Comment: All the functions run independently, I don't think your time trigger is causing this issue, you should check for other deadlocks, which might be CRM calls or other resource calls.